# Plotly: How to find coefficient of trendline in plotly express?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, statsmodels

How do you find the coefficient of the trend line in plotly express?

For example I used the code below to chart the trend line but now I want to know the coefficient.

```py
import plotly.express as px

px.scatter(df, x='x_data', y='y_data', trendline="ols")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you need to have a look at plotly [doc](https://plotly.com/python/linear-fits/#fitting-multiple-lines-and-retrieving-the-model-parameters) in `plotly` and  [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.html) one. I think the example in the plotly example should be fixed. Anyway

```py
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="total_bill", y="tip", trendline="ols")
fig.show()
```

For the results you should run

```py
results = px.get_trendline_results(fig)
results = results.iloc[0]["px_fit_results"].summary()
print(results)
```

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       0.457
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.454
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     203.4
Date:                Mon, 10 Aug 2020   Prob (F-statistic):           6.69e-34
Time:                        12:28:52   Log-Likelihood:                -350.54
No. Observations:                 244   AIC:                             705.1
Df Residuals:                     242   BIC:                             712.1
Df Model:                           1                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const          0.9203      0.160      5.761      0.000       0.606       1.235
x1             0.1050      0.007     14.260      0.000       0.091       0.120
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                       20.185   Durbin-Watson:                   1.811
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):               37.750
Skew:                           0.443   Prob(JB):                     6.35e-09
Kurtosis:                       4.711   Cond. No.                         53.0
==============================================================================
```

While for the coefficients

```py
results.iloc[0]["px_fit_results"].params
```

```
array([0.92026961, 0.10502452])
```

Where the fist one is the constant while the second is the slope.

Comment: `results = px.get_trendline_results(fig)`. Nice! Could you include where you found this?

Comment: In the first link I added. [This](https://plotly.com/python/linear-fits/#fitting-multiple-lines-and-retrieving-the-model-parameters). But the next line in documentation is not working for me. I should open an issue.

Comment: Ah! I didn't notice the links at first glance. Maybe because I was browsing on my phone... And yes, it would be great if you would consider opening an issue.

Comment: This is great. Point to note, if you update the results variable with .summary() then .params gives error (can be obvious but just mentioning to avoid errors if code is run as is. So,  


`results.iloc[0]["px_fit_results"].summary()`

OR  

`results.iloc[0]["px_fit_results"].params`