# Plotly: How to retrieve regression results using plotly express?

Tags: python, plotly, regression

You can easily plot a regression line using plotly express / px.scatter and retrieve regression results like [beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63341840/plotly-how-to-find-coefficient-of-trendline-in-plotly-express/63344269#63344269) using `px.get_trendline_results(fig).iloc[0]["px_fit_results"].params[1]`. But how can you retrieve other parameters like R-squared or p-vales for the coefficients?

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Code:

```
# imports
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# data
np.random.seed(123)
numdays=20
X = (np.random.randint(low=-20, high=20, size=numdays).cumsum()+100).tolist()
Y = (np.random.randint(low=-20, high=20, size=numdays).cumsum()+100).tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': X, 'Y':Y})

# figure using px.scatter
fig = px.scatter(df, x="X", y="Y", trendline="ols", template = 'plotly_dark')

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The answer:

```
model = px.get_trendline_results(fig)
results = model.iloc[0]["px_fit_results"]
alpha = params[0]
beta = .params[1]
p_beta = .pvalues[1]
r_squared = .rsquared
```

#### Details:

All regression results are available through:

```
px.get_trendline_results(fig)
```

Which, when run, will return a somewhat cryptic looking pandas dataframe:

```
                                      px_fit_results
0  <statsmodels.regression.linear_model.Regressio...
```

The element under `px_fit_results` is an object of type `statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResultsWrapper` which is a wrapper for statsmodels.

So if we simplify matters a bit by setting:

```
models = px.get_trendline_results(fig)
```

And:

```
results =  model.iloc[0]["px_fit_results"]
```

Then we can check what's available in that object using:

```
dir(results)
```

And find all the regression details one should need, like:

```
'predict',
'pvalues',
'remove_data',
'resid',
'resid_pearson',
'rsquared',
'rsquared_adj',
'save',
'scale',
'ssr',
'summary',
'summary2',
't_test',
't_test_pairwise',
```

But note that all these available results can be structured differently.

Running `results.rsquared` will return a single float `0.611901357827784`, while running `results.pvalues` will return an array `array([9.95834884e-01, 4.59734574e-05])`. Which again will be subsettable for the constant and trendline through `results.pvalues[0]` and `results.pvalues[1]`, respectively.

With this information available, you could for example extract some of them and include them as annotations to further improve your plotly figures:

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

# data
np.random.seed(123)
numdays=20
X = (np.random.randint(low=-20, high=20, size=numdays).cumsum()+100).tolist()
Y = (np.random.randint(low=-20, high=20, size=numdays).cumsum()+100).tolist()

df = pd.DataFrame({'X': X, 'Y':Y})

# Figure using plotly express
fig = px.scatter(df, x="X", y="Y", trendline="ols", template = 'plotly_dark')

# retrieve model estimates
model = px.get_trendline_results(fig)
results = model.iloc[0]["px_fit_results"]
alpha = results.params[0]
beta = results.params[1]
p_beta = results.pvalues[1]
r_squared = results.rsquared

line1 = 'y = ' + str(round(alpha, 4)) + ' + ' + str(round(beta, 4))+'x'
line2 = 'p-value = ' + '{:.5f}'.format(p_beta)
line3 = 'R^2 = ' + str(round(r_squared, 3))
summary = line1 + '<br>' + line2 + '<br>' + line3


fig.add_annotation(
        x=110,
        y=140,
        xref="x",
        yref="y",
        text=summary,
        showarrow=False,
        font=dict(
            family="Courier New, monospace",
            size=16,
            color="#ffffff"
            ),
        align="left",
        arrowhead=2,
        arrowsize=1,
        arrowwidth=2,
        arrowcolor="#636363",
        ax=20,
        ay=-30,
        borderwidth=2,
        borderpad=4,
        bgcolor="rgba(100,100,100, 0.6)",
        opacity=0.8
        )

fig.show()
```